# Unable to find alternative for connect by level in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, regexp-replace

```
select 
trim(regexp_substr(t.column_A, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value)) as column_A 

from (SELECT * FROM table_t t ) t, 

table(cast(multiset(select level from dual 
connect by level <= length (regexp_replace(t.column_A, '[^,]+')) + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
```

Not able to find alternate for connect by level in postgresql.
Also the dual don't exist in postgresql.

It would be great help if someone  help me to identify alternative for the above posted query.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Without an explanation on what that code does, this is nearly impossible to answer. Chances are that you just want `select * from table_t t cross join unnest(string_to_array(t.column_a, ',')) as x(column_a)`

Comment: Independent of the DBMS, the part `from (SELECT * FROM table_t t ) t` can be simplified to `from table_t t`

Comment: The postgres equivalent is a recursive CTE. (should also work on Oracle) And: you don't need the `dual`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not define your `table_t` so I will assume that `column_a` is a comma separated string as that appears to be what the Oracle is looking for. If that is correct then perhaps the simplest approach is to transform the string to an array, then unroll the array. Fortunately, Postgres provides  single function for each action string_to_array and unnest respectively. (See documentation: [Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html)).

```
with table_t( column_a) as
     ( values ( 'abc,defgh,ijklm,nopqr,stuvw,zyz0123,456789'))
select unnest (string_to_array(column_a,','))
  from table_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10);
```

will generate rows with numbers between 1 and 10 the same way as

```
select level from dual connect by level <= 10
```

does in Oracle